# Ways to pass info to the next page in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know one way to pass information to another page in Javascript is to use a get request and put everything on the URL.  But are there any other ways?

Is it possible for the Javascript to read post requests or data on a form?  Are there any ways to use browser cache or somehow have page A manage and manipulate the loading of page B?

Comment: The HTML5 specification introduces *web storage* (http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). Other than that, you will have to stick to the established patterns afaic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think the best answer is store.js https://github.com/frankkohlhepp/store-js.  It uses localstorage or other solutions on older browsers.

Comment: I so love these "kind" of scripts :)

Answer (score 5):

[Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) with the attribute `path=/` are available to all documents within the domain and are available both in the web browser (via JavaScript) and on the server.

Also [web storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage) is able to persist arbitrary data within the web browser but it is less widely supported than Cookies.

Comment: Cookies are bound to *a* document.

Comment: @FK82: not entirely; if the cookie has the attribute `path=/` then it is available to *all* documents in the domain.

Comment: @FK82: no worries, anyway it is very much worth mentioning explicitly, so I updated my answer =)

Answer (score 1):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) - a Javascript API for storing and retrieving smallish strings on the client, local to a particular domain, is one way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Web Storage supports persistant data storage, you can store the data in browser sandbox and again retrieve the data. This way you can have "your page A manage loading of page B".

For example:

```
if (localStorage.cnt){
    localStorage.cnt= localStorage.cnt + 1;
}
else localStorage.cnt=1;
alert(localStorage.cnt);
```